# Sharepoint List webservice error on CheckoutFile method with SSL

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint

I am trying to checkout a file from a SharePoint document library before downloading to my client application for edit.

```
//documentPath = https://192.168.1.10/Utility/Phys/Document%20Library/document.xml
//listWebServiceURL = https://192.168.1.10/Utility/Phys/Document%20Library/_vti_bin/lists.asmx
private void CheckOutFile(string documentPath)
{
    string listWebServiceUrl = this.GetListServiceURL(documentPath);
    bool checkedOut;

    using (Lists listWebService = new Lists())
    {
        listWebService.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        listWebService.Url = listWebServiceUrl;
        checkedOut = listWebService.CheckOutFile(documentPath, "true", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

When the checkedOut = listWebService.CheckOutFile(documentPath, "true", string.Empty); line runs I get a SOAPServerException.

((System.Xml.XmlElement)((System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException)(ex)).Detail).InnerText
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thank you,
Keith

EDIT:
I have tested the above code against a SharePoint library that does not use SSL and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is an alternate access mapping problem (The "Object Not Set" error is a telltale sign)? You've got one for https://192.168.1.10/ in Central Administration->Operations->Global Configuration->Alternate Access Mappings, ya?

Comment: I think you may be onto something.  I stumbled onto this a little earlier, by changing the url I was using from the IP address to the hostname of the server and it started to work.  I will look into the Alternate Access Mappings now.  Thank you.

Comment: Yep, if you can access the site through a browser but not hit any of the web services, then alternate access mappings are your first port of call.

Comment: I agree, because I get this error in Sharepoint when trying to check out an Office (Excel) document just via Microsoft Internet Explorer: "object reference not set to an instance of an object".  Using http://intranet/ causes the error, but using http://intranet.company.za.local/ (FQDN) works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to provide a time value in the last argument in listWebService.CheckOutFile. It may be complaining about the string.Empty. Try putting in a string like; "12 May 2009 22:00:00 GMT"

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.checkoutfile.aspx on the lastModified timestamp:    If this parameter contains a value, the server compares the submitted lastModified value with the stored lastModified value. If the values do not match, the check-out fails and this method returns false.   Will test out your suggestion.

Comment: Ok.. Tried it with the Date Modified that is listed for that item in the document library, no luck.  I tried it with null in place of string.empty, no luck.  Same exception each time.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this Object Reference error and got it to work by adding the domain to the URL.
    http://servername - gets an error,
but 
    http://servername.domain.com  - *checkout worked*

Makes sense that by being fully qualified it's clearly in the intranet zone for alternate access mappings.